# Checking existence of a column before adding

Tags: ios, sql, swift

This is a small part of the data in my table `PLANT` I'm having in database...

```
 id    name      code
123   OFFICE1   A1234
456   OFFICE2   B4567
789   OFFICE3   C8989
```

When I get all the data from an api, before inserting them into the database, I want to check if any records are present already.

This is how I'm checking if a record is present..

```
 let isExists = sharedInstance.plantExists(thePlantObject, id: 123)


func plantExists(_ items: plant,id: Int) -> Bool {
    var isExists = false
    sharedInstance.database!.open()

    isExists = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate("EXISTS(SELECT * FROM PLANT WHERE PLANT.id = ?)", withArgumentsIn: [id])

    sharedInstance.database!.close()
    return isExists
}
```

But if I print `isExists`, then this message is printed... `(Bool) isExists = <variable not available>`

What am I doing wrong here..?

Comment: Most likely because your sql query fails, I am not aware of a function EXISTS in sql. Are you sure your database support that query, normally the operator EXISTS is used as part of a WHERE clause such as `SELECT * from tableA WHERE EXISTS(SELECT...)`

Comment: Maybe off topic but why are you calling a function named `executeUpdate` when you are only reading data?

Comment: `executeUpdate` was used for other operations also like INSERT, JOIN, UPDATE, DELETE ..@JoakimDanielson

Comment: I also used a query like this `SELECT id FROM PLANT WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM PLANT WHERE PLANT.id = 123`. But it is giving a crash..

Comment: So then why use executeUpdate when you are not doing an insert, delete or update, this could be very important depending on what `executeUpdate` returns? No point in having double queries, use `SELECT id FROM PLANT WHERE PLANT.id = 123` or `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PLANT WHERE PLANT.id = 123` depending on what works best.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the schema of db then make sure id attribute is set as unique and insertion will fail if you are inserting id which already exists in the column.

Or Just do select query with id and see if any results come back to you

> Select * from  where id =

Answer (score 0):

As per comment @Joakim Danielson, `EXISTS` should be a part of `WHERE` clause.

You can achieve it feature two way

#### 1. The way you are approaching (checking existence and based on that insert).

Instead of using `EXISTS` use following query

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM PLANT WHERE PLANT.id = ?
```

This way you can get the count of specific `id`. Here i assume that you didn't put any `UNIQUE` constraints in `id` column. If you set `UNIQUE` constraint in `id` column, then second approach is the best approach for you.

#### 2. Let the SQLite handle itself (based on a constraint)

While create the db schema, make the `id` unique. Assumed schema creation query is following

```
CREATE TABLE plant (
   id INT(11) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   name VARCHAR(255)
);
```

use following query while inserting

```
INSERT OR IGNORE (`id`, `name`) VALUES (?, ?)
```

This way, it will ignore inserting if any sort of constraint fails.

Working demo is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7c986/2/0).

NB: It won't report any failure.